# How to save token local storage by HTTP post request when submit the form using angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I submit my Gmail. Then token generates successfully but the problem is I want to use that token to reset my password. So I want to save that token for local storage when submitting the form by HTTP post request. And that same token I want to use for my HTTP put method which I use for update password.

[This image shows my token in google chrome when submit my forgot password form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyjJa.png)

> Authentication Service

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
constructor(){}
  sendEmail(user: User): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${applicationUrl.user.forgotpassword}`, user.email);
  }

  resetPassword(user: User): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put<any>(`${applicationUrl.user.resetpassword}`, user.password, { params });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am getting it correctly you want to store and retrieve data from localStorage. You can store data in localStorage using.

```
localStorage.setItem('key', value)
```

here you value will be token `respone.data`

While doing reset password you can get same from storage using

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('key');
```

I hope it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Can we try something like this?

```
sendEmail("abcUser").subscribe(token => {
 console.log(JSON.stringify(token));
 var data = token.data;  // Parse and read data value
 localStorage.setItem('token', data);});
```

In resetPassword() method, we can read from localStorage and pass that token.